# How to load a huggingface dataset from local path?

Tags: python, huggingface, huggingface-datasets, huggingface-hub

Take a simple example in this website, https://huggingface.co/datasets/Dahoas/rm-static:

if I want to load this dataset online, I just directly use,

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("Dahoas/rm-static")
```

What if I want to load dataset from local path, so I download the files and keep the same folder structure from web `Files and versions` fristly,

```
-data
|-test-00000-of-00001-bf4c733542e35fcb.parquet
|-train-00000-of-00001-2a1df75c6bce91ab.parquet
-.gitattributes
-README.md
-dataset_infos.json
```

Then,put them into my folder, but shows error when loading,

```
dataset_path ="/data/coco/dataset/Dahoas/rm-static"
tmp_dataset = load_dataset(dataset_path)
```

It shows,`FileNotFoundError: No (supported) data files or dataset script found in /data/coco/dataset/Dahoas/rm-static.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the data with `save_to_disk` then load it with `load_from_disk`. For example:

```
import datasets
ds = datasets.load_dataset("Dahoas/rm-static") 
ds.save_to_disk("Path/to/save")
```

and later if you wanna re-utilize it just normal load_dataset will work

```
ds = datasets.load_from_disk("Path/to/save")
```

you can verify the same by printing the dataset you will be getting same result for both. This is the easier way out. The file format it is generally saved in is arrow.

For the second method where you are downloading the parquet file. Would require you to explicitly declaring the dataset and it config, might be included in json and then you can load it.

Comment: Would suggest to go by first method might be time consuming but lot better in term of saving effort and time the next time you load the data. Please feel free to post anymore question over this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have tried your method, but when I load the dataset by `dataset = load_dataset("Path/to/save")` it shows that error, raise ValueError(f"Couldn't cast\n{table.schema}\nto\n{features}\nbecause column names don't match")
ValueError: Couldn't cast
_data_files: list<item: struct<filename: string>>
  child 0, item: struct<filename: string>
      child 0, filename: string
_fingerprint: string
_format_columns: null
_format_kwargs: struct<>
_format_type: null
_output_all_columns: bool
_split: string
to
{'builder_name': Value(dtype='string', id=None), }

Comment: On the other hand, if I use `dataset = load_from_disk("Path/to/save")` it didn't show a problem

Comment: Hi @4daJKong. That is the correct way to do it. Were you able to load it that way? you can refer same at https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/loading_methods

Answer (score 4):

I solved this question by myself, it is easyily to use,

```
data_files = {“train”:“train-00000-of-00001-2a1df75c6bce91ab.parquet”,“test”:“test-00000-of-00001-8c7c51afc6d45980.parquet”}
raw_datasets = load_dataset(“parquet”, data_dir=‘/Your/Path/Dahoas/rm-static/data’, data_files=data_files)
```